# Is there a way to pull all strings between a word and a character?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regexes to pull all function declarations from a long string. Right now I'm trying to use the pattern `function\|(.*?)\|\}` to pull all strings where the first word is `function` and the last character is `}` followed by a blank line. I'm not too well-versed with regexes so I'm not sure what I've done wrong but I haven't been able to get any matches.

Is there a better/easier pattern to use for this?

My Current Attempt/Implementation:

```
import re

def pull_functions(source_code):
    pattern = "function\|(.*?)\|\}"

    # substring = re.search(pattern, source_code).group(1)
    # print(substring)
    matches = re.findall(
        pattern=r'function\|(.*?)\|\}',
        string=source_code
    )

    print(matches)

    return
```

An example of what `source_code` could be:

```
function foo()
        public
        returns (bool)
{
        ... Function Contents ...
}

/**
 * Some information about this functions...      
 */
function bar(type v1, type v2)
    public
    returns (bool)
{
    ... Function Contents ...
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to extract the source code for entire functions?  If so, then regex isn't the right tool for this.  For example, if any function has an `if { ... }` inside it, your pattern would stop prematurely.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I'm trying to get the source code for all functions...would I have to just loop over the file then?

Comment: Honestly, you would need to write some kind of _parser_ here.  One simple approach would be to use regex to find `\bfunction \w+\(.*?\) \{`.  Then, from that point, use a stack to keep track of `{` and `}`.  The end of the function is when you find a `}` such that there no net brackets in your stack.

Answer (score 0):

Is following regex match your requirement?

```
(^\s*function\s+(.*\s)+?\})
```

then capture Group1. In case inside method there is only if {....} it can able to handle that.

https://regex101.com/r/sUzn5Y/1

Comment: @Kmandai this almost works, but I need each function to be a separate match. Currently seeing if I can add a newline requirement somehow...so that the occurence of the word "function" starts a new group. See issue here: https://regex101.com/r/sUzn5Y/2